# Integração de função retorna erro "only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars"

Tags: python, array

Estou a tentar integrar uma função num determinado intervalo que mostra o fluxo de partículas numa direção de angulo zero (theta) em função da energia E das partículas. Já tentei várias formas e obtive erros diferentes mas este é o que persiste sempre no fim. O meu conhecimento de Python é limitado e não estou a entender como obter o integral.

A minha função neste momento está assim:

```
from numpy import radians, cos, arange
from matplotlib.pyplot import plot, yscale, xscale, xlabel, ylabel
from scipy.integrate import quad

def integral(self):
     theta=0
     E = arange(1, 5000, 1)
     costh = cos(radians(theta))
     a = 18 / (E * costh + 145)
     b = (E + 2.7 / costh)**-2.7
     c = (E + 5) / (E + 5 / costh)
     #flux = a*b*c*1**4
     return ((a*b*c*1**4))
     #print(flux)

     """
     plot(flux)
     yscale('log')
     xscale('log')
     xlabel('E')
     ylabel('Fluxo')
     """

#integral(0)

A, err= quad(integral, 500, 1000)
```

Se eu retirar o self do argumento da função obtenho o erro:

"integral() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given"

Não sei como resolver.

Alguém sabe o solução para este caso?